# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3' even after downloading the library

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pyttsx3

Even after downloading the library `pyttsx3` it cannot import. It says: `lmodule not found error`.

[image]

I tried all the methods available as:

- using `pipenv`
- upgrading `pip`

But I am still dealing with same problem:

[image]

Comment: What was the output of `pip install pyttsx3`?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, what I did is reinstall python to the newest version, once I had it I installed it using `pip3 install pyttsx3`, and it solved the problem for me.

(note that I'm using `pip3` because I' using python3 for my project, it shouldn't cause problem to use `pip` but just to make sure)

Answer (score 0):

Try download whl file of pyttsx3 from [here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/9a/de4781245f5ad966646fd276259ef7cfd400ba3cf7d5db7c0d5aab310c20/pyttsx3-2.90-py3-none-any.whl).

For example download it to `F:/file`.

Then use `pip install F:/file/pyttsx3-2.90-py3-none-any.whl` to install.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with pyttsx3 is that it does not work for python version 3.4,3.5,3.6
But it works for python 3.8 and above but in the documentation, it is mentioned it works woth any python above version 3+